# Printing the Data in a NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing

How would print what is in my NSTableView? The View uses core data so everything is stored and can be grabbed as an NSArray. But how would I go about printing it out? At the moment when you click the print button it just seems to take a picture of the view and print that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this works exactly as documented. The view is asked for its PDF representation (which, for an unmodified table view, is exactly what you see on screen), then this gets printed.

A view's [drawing can be customized](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_printapps/osxp_printapps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000861-SW1) for printing versus on-screen drawing, but for a table view, this is more trouble than it's worth.

It might be easiest to generate an HTML representation of the table, then print that. You can use WebKit or just a plain NSAttributedString and off-screen NSTextView. The trick there is to generate the HTML, create an attributed string with the HTML data (there's a method just for that), then hand that to the off-screen text view. The text view would be sized as desired, then you just tell it to print. This gives you control over pagination as WebKit doesn't currently support the print-specific parts of CSS (in other words, it's "screen-only").

Comment: Interesting approach, how would I generate the HTML and then what method would I use to create an attributed string with the HTML data? Cheers.

Comment: How to create the HTML? You'd iterate through your data set and generate the appropriate table HTML. As for how to create the attributed string, the appropriate HTML methods are in the NSAttributed String AppKit Additions: http://bit.ly/aHZdZ6

Comment: How does this technique give you control over pagination? I have my HTML page printing just fine, but I want to print multiple HTML pages in a row, but each HTML page should start on a new page. When I added them all to the same NSMutableString, then loaded that into a web view, all I got was one page right after the other. I wanted each page separate. Just loading the HTML into an NSTextView and printing that will do this somehow?

Comment: HTML itself does not support pagination. CSS standard does allow for page breaks but the last time I checked (sometime last year) WebKit does not yet support CSS pagination. So, the short answer is: It doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is taken the data and drawn it to a NSView based object in a way that the end-user would want to print. The user then prints that. it's in the docs.

I like Joshua Nozzi's idea, probably much simpler than custom drawing...