# Cocoa print data nstableview on pdf

Tags: cocoa, printing

I have this questions

1. Can I print on paper datas inside NSTableView like table ?
2. Can I generate pdf ?
3. Which class can I use ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is likely using HTML representation of the table displayed in [Webview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
see this previous question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297209/printing-the-data-in-a-nstableview)

Comment: What are steps ? 
Do I convert NSTableView like string HTML ?